# increase quantity to 5 to all products that are out of stock in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have many products in my store that have quantity 0. I want to change it to 5. Can it be done from the database with some sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research, I have found the solution. 
Run the following sql statement in phpmyadmin:

```
  UPDATE ps_stock_available SET quantity=5 WHERE quantity=0
```

But remember to clear the cache in preferences> performance

Comment: Have you combinations?